# Python openCV TypeError: labels data type = 18 is not supported

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Part of my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2, os, time
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, label, initial_image):
        self.label = label
        self.image_list = [initial_image]
        self.recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
        print(label)
        print(type(label))
        self.recognizer.train([initial_image], np.array([label]))
```

And The place that i call it:

```
...
...
...

        gray_image_list = self.create_image_list(image_path_list)
        t.tick("Images Created and Converted To Gray Scale :")
        face_list = self.detect_and_crop_faces(gray_image_list)
        t.tick(print_text="Faces Detected :")
        i = 0
        for face in face_list:
            self.train_image(face)
            t.tick(print_text="For " + str(i) + " image  Total Calculate Time :")
            i += 1
```

traceback:

```
Detecting Faces   ->  Faces Detected :   1.80294  sn.
Traceback (most recent call last):
subject01.gif_0
<type 'str'>
  File "face_recognizer/self_learner.py", line 143, in <module>
    st.run()
  File "face_recognizer/self_learner.py", line 136, in run
    self.train_image(face)
  File "face_recognizer/self_learner.py", line 117, in train_image
    self.trainer_dict[face.label] = Trainer(face.label, face.image)
  File "face_recognizer/self_learner.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.recognizer.train([initial_image], np.array([label]))
TypeError: labels data type = 18 is not supported
```

"label" is a regular string. Any idea why i get this error?

Comment: "label" is a regular string - that is wrong. it should be an array of integers. also, rather train once only on a list of images, and a list of labels, not on a single image

Comment: Yes. i found the same thing while digging. I saw your post after i post my answer. Post yours and i ll accept as answer (:

Comment: your own one is as fine , keep it. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok i found the part that cause problem. **label** must be an integer, It doesnt accept string.